# Can I access the shrine near Kakariko village after completing the rest of the game?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've done every possible quest in Kakariko. I am also unable to obtain the shrine ball through the event. Is it possible that I broke it due to me completing the game and ignoring that event? I didn't know it existed until now.

I already know about the quests needed, I simply missed the event.

I completed all Kakariko Side/Shrine Quests. I am at post-Endgame and accidentally ignored this event in my run. I've done the event on a different profile and it worked.

Comment: Are you saying that the ball has disappeared, or glitched out in some way? Or are you asking how to obtain it to complete the Shrine quest?

Comment: I think the save file is just glitched. Like I had said, I completed the criteria for the event, but I didn't know it existed and moved on. At this point I am trying for 100% completion, which is impossible with whatever is happening.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what is happening that makes the ball unobtainable? For example, does Impa stop you from taking the Orb and have you done the four side quests required beforehand?

Comment: MBorg I have completed the side quests, but ignored the event by moving on. Impa stops me even though you don't even get it there in the first place.

Comment: What does it say in your shrine quest log under 'The Stolen Heirloom'?

Answer (score 3):

## You've started the quest but don't know how to do it

From what I can tell, you have obtained the Stolen Heirloom shrine quest. If that is correct, you are on the right track, but you simply don't know how to progress in the quest. If you would like to know, keep reading. If you would prefer to find out yourself, stop reading now.

**Note:** If you are stuck but don't want the entire solution, you should read steps 1-3.

1. > Wait until nighttime, around 10-11 PM to give yourself enough time.
2. > Head to Kakariko Village.
3. > Get on top of the gate at the entrance to Impa's house. You can use Revali's Gale or you can paraglide down from in front of her doors.
4. > Wait for Dorian to start walking.
5. > Wait until Dorian walks a fair distance away – far enough away that he doesn't notice you.
6. > Prepare your Stealth Armor, drink a Sneaky Elixir, and/or eat stealth-increasing food, if you have it.
7. > Get off of the gate, and start slowly pursuing Dorian. If he notices you, you will need to start over.
8. > After pursuing Dorian for a fair amount of time, he will stop at a shrine pedestal. Walk towards the shrine pedestal, and kill the Yiga Blademaster that spawns.
9. > Go through Dorian's dialogue and pick up the ancient orb. Throw it into the pedestal to reveal the shrine.